# Apple Photos and iCloud

Tags: macos, icloud, photos.app

So from what I understood, if I have Apple Photos on my Mac set up with iCloud it will upload Photos to iCloud and only store a representation locally, thus free local disk space.

I have now importet a bunch of folders and my disk only has 112 MB of free space, so I'd assume there is enough "storage pressure" for deleting local copies but I cannot see any upload status nor does it appear that Photos wants to reduce local disk space.

Edit:

It appears Photos stopped uploading for lack of local disk space, which will be the primary reason why it cannot upload and it cannot free local disk space.
[image: upload for ... objects stopped. lack of local disk space]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score -1):

Storing the photos in iCloud only and not on local disk is possible, but it’s not the default. In the Photos app go to Preferences, select the iCloud tab and make sure that “Optimize Mac Storage” is selected.

Comment: That option is enabled